# jQuery: quick way to say close this, open that?

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a series of divs, with the following classes: dots-1, dots-2, dots-3, dots-4
Only ".dots-1" is visible when the page opens; the other 3 divs are hidden.  You have to click a button on each div in order to reveal the next div - i.e. On dots-1, you click on button-1, which closes dots-1 and opens dots-2.  On dots-2, you click on button-2, which closes dots-2 and opens dots-3.

```
<div class="dots-1">
    Text 1
    <a class="button-1">Go to 2</a>
</div>

<div class="dots-2">
    Text 2
    <a class="button-1">Go to 3</a>
</div>

<div class="dots-3">
    Text 3
    <a class="button-1">Go to 4</a>
</div>

<div class="dots-4">
    Text 4
    <a class="button-1">End</a>
</div>

<style>
    .dots-2, .dots-3, .dots-4{display:none;}
</style>
```

Is there a quick, compact way to write the jQuery code that closes each div and opens the next div, when each button is clicked?

Otherwise, I would write out a long jQuery code saying: When button-1 is clicked, close dots-1 and open dots-2. When button-2 is clicked, close dots-2 and open dots-3.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML and we can better advise how to use the nature of your HTML structure to make a single generic solution.

Comment: I would wrap them all in another div and set have only 1 of them with an `enabled` class or something of the kind. The script will find the parent `div`'s next sibling (if any) and display it. Then, you do not have to change your CSS and you can use only 1 selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( "a[class^='button']" ).click(function () {
     $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
});
```

You can also check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4FPs/)